# base64 decode a mysql column before performing a WHERE

Tags: mysql, base64

Basically - its a long story - but I have a field in a database that is encoded as a base64 string.

EG: this is stored in the database:

```
YToyOntzOjIwOiJUeXBlX29mX29yZ2FuaXNhdGlvbiI7czoyMDoiTWVtYmVyIG9mIFBhcmxpYW1lbnQiO3M6ODoiUG9zdGNvZGUiO3M6NzoiUEUxIDFKQSI7fQ==
```

Which equals this:

```
a:2:{s:20:"Type_of_organisation";s:20:"Member of Parliament";s:8:"Postcode";s:7:"#postcode#";}
```

What I want to be able to do is select where this string `LIKE '%Member of Parliament%'`. Is there any way to base64 decode a mysql column before performing a `WHERE`?

eg: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE base64_decode(column) LIKE '%Member of Parliament%'`

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [base64 encode in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358500/base64-encode-in-mysql)

Comment: What version of MYSQL are you using ?
Maybe you can write a UDF for this?

Comment: possibly... lack of an answer though. Plus I'm looking to decode, not encode.

Comment: Mysql 5.0.5 - what's a UDF? I've found a stored procedure online, but apparently it's extremely inefficient.

Comment: User defined function

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.6.1 or higher you can use the FROM_BASE64() function:

> Takes a string encoded with the base-64 encoded rules used by TO_BASE64() and returns the decoded result as a binary string. The result is NULL if the argument is NULL or not a valid base-64 string. See the description of TO_BASE64() for details about the encoding and decoding rules.
>
> This function was added in MySQL 5.6.1.
>
> mysql> SELECT TO_BASE64('abc'), FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64('abc'));
>           -> 'JWJj', 'abc'

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64

Otherwise you can use the User Defined Function from: https://github.com/y-ken/mysql-udf-base64

Comment: Is there an equivalent function in MySQL 5.1?

Comment: Not that I know, you'll have to define your own function with the base64.sql

Comment: Link is broken to wi-fizzle

Comment: Thanks @ImmortalFirefly, found another link. Let me know if this works for you.