# User lookup on encrypted database fields

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, hash

Essentially I've got a table holding user data, all of which is AES encrypted (in BLOB fields).

This means that none of those fields can be indexed which will slow down any queries on that table - especially since the entire table will need decrypting before any matches can be made...

```
... WHERE AES_DECRYPT(`user`.`email`, '{$sSomeKeyHere}') = '{$sSubmittedEmail}'
```

So, what I want is a field that just contains a hash value, unencrypted, that can be indexed to use as a quick lookup. The best lookup will probably be some derivative of the email address (lowercase, reversed and hashed or some other replicable process) so that you can effectively search on the email address without having to decrypt the email address... but I need to keep that secure.

So, options I'm mulling over:

1: just lower-case and SHA-256 (or 512) hash the email address before inserting it into the database

2: slightly more convoluted; lower-case plus some other replicable function of scrambling the email address before hashing it.

3: creating a salt string from `user.last_login_date` (which isn't encrypted) and using that to create a salted hash with the email address - and updating the lookup field every time the user logs in (because the salt will have changed). However this requires a slightly more convoluted `SELECT` statement, limited to whatever hashing functions are built into the MySQL engine, as I'll need to recreate the hash using the last login date to perform the search.

---

So the question is, is it OK to just take option 1?

Is option 2 better?

Is option 3 as totally overkill as I think it is?

Or have I missed something totally obvious and there is, in fact, a much better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1.

Your data can be indexed for searching and comparison, but only against encrypted search terms.

Comment: I think I'll go with option 1 then - since the whole point is to create a secure indexable field based on the email address (from user input) and AFAICT using a hash on a VARCHAR (or similar) is the only way to achieve this with MySQL. It's not really a complex search, just a quick identifier to put into the `WHERE` of a `SELECT` to retrieve the data for validation or whatever. Gives me an indexed search on the email address so that I get a quick query and only have to decrypt a single row rather than the entire table :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use reversed one?

```
... WHERE `user`.`email` = AES_ENCRYPT('{$sSubmittedEmail}'`, '{$sSomeKeyHere}')
```

And encrypted strings can be stored into `VARCHAR` type via `base64` or something similar functions.

Comment: *blinks* ... so option 4 then :) I did miss something obvious! I like the elegance but I didn't think MySQL (on MyISAM for reasons best left ignored) allowed you to insert AES encrypted strings into anything other than BLOB fields? Correction - just checked, it'll work on TEXT fields as well... but again that can't be indexed (apart from FULLTEXT)

Comment: If you're using MySQL 5.6 or above, just use `TO_BASE64` to make the encrypted binary into a string. If not, do encrypt and decrypt in application level or add Base64 UDF. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358500/base64-encode-in-mysql

Comment: Unfortunately it's MySQL 5.1 (Slackware is quite conservative with its builds) - and base64 encoding at the application level can, as I understand it, incorporate `0x0` into the string - which is the terminator in VARCHAR fields - so again, it'll only work with BLOB or TEXT? I was looking into it after your post to see if I could make it work; essentially it's recreating AES_ENCRYPT in the application and getting a base64 encoded string into a VARCHAR... which I wasn't having much luck with tbh :\

Comment: base64 can encode any binary into string. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 Thus, you can store it into 'normal' character type column and also can create an index for it. Trust me.

Comment: Thanks - I'll persevere with it for a bit tomorrow :)