# Convert SHA1 password to its binary form

Tags: ruby, bash, sha1, hexdump

I have a database with passwords encrypted in SHA1, I need to convert them to the SHA1 binary form and encode with base64, how can I get that?

This is what I have:

```
# echo -n "password" | openssl sha1
5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8
```

This is what I need:

```
# echo -n "password" | openssl sha1 -binary | base64
W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358500/base64-encode-in-mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'digest/sha1'
require 'base64'

Base64.encode64(Digest::SHA1.digest('password'))
# => "W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=\n"
```

this adds a newline though so you may need to use

```
Base64.encode64(Digest::SHA1.digest('password')).chop
# => "W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g="
```

or even simpler, as `@FrederickCheung` suggested:

```
Digest::SHA1.base64digest('password')
```

---

### Edit

when you only have the hex string of the SHA-1 encoded password, then do

```
require 'base64'

pass = "5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8"
Base64.encode64([pass].pack('H*')).chop
# => "W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g="
```

or you can even bypass the `base64` library and solely rely on `pack`:

```
[[pass].pack('H*')].pack('m0')
# => "W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g="
```

Comment: or even `Digest::SHA1.base64digest('password')`

Comment: I don't have the password in plain, only the crypted form

Comment: @padde that works too, thanks, I didn't heard before about `pack`

Comment: @tictacbum `pack` is very powerful and has a brother called `unpack`. It's the easiest way to fiddle with binary data in ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 approach:

```
import sys, base64

def hex_to_b64(word):
    number = int(word, base=16)
    bytestr = number.to_bytes(20, 'big')
    b64 = base64.b64encode(bytestr).decode('ascii')
    return b64

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for word in sys.argv[1:]:
        print(hex_to_b64(word))
```

which gives

```
localhost-2:coding $ python3 shaswitch.py 5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8
W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=
```

Comment: that sounds fine, but it throws an error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'

Comment: I'm using Python 3.2-- I'm afraid I can't remember offhand when to_bytes was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Why resort to python; OP wanted bash:

```
% openssl sha1 -binary <(echo -n 'password') | base64
W6ph5Mm5Pz8GgiULbPgzG37mj9g=
```