# MySQL MD5 hash to base64

Tags: mysql, sql, base64, md5

I have a mysql db that stores all my users info (username, pass, etc). I am building an LDAP server with back-sql and everything works fine except the password field. All passwords are basic MD5 hashes so

`select MD5('testPass01')`

returns

`428a65ed9de7dbf8ef7d08f884528440`

Apparently that is a hexpair representation of a binary value. LDAP will understand a base64 encoded string which is something like this

`{MD5}Qopl7Z3n2/jvfQj4hFKEQA==`

I found a perl script that does the conversion

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Base64;
use strict;
my @md5 = split "",$ARGV[0];
my @res;
for (my $i = 0 ; $i < 32 ; $i+=2)
{
my $c = (((hex $md5[$i]) << 4) % 255) | (hex $md5[$i+1]);
$res[$i/2] = chr $c;
print $c;
}
print "{MD5}".encode_base64(join "", @res);
#-------------------------------------------#
```

My question is: Is it possible to do the conversion using SQL through a stored procedure? I cannot install MySQL server 5.6 which includes base64 encode and decode functions

Thanks

Comment: This previous post contains a BASE64_ENCODE function - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358500/base64-encode-in-mysql

Comment: I am using that but from what I understand, on line 7 of the perl script I have in the post, I need to get the hex value of each character and bitshift by 4, then OR it with the hex value of the character next to it. Then convert that to a CHAR. Once that is done then I can use the BASE64_ENCODE

Comment: ok I am figured out that if you use `select BASE64_ENCODE(unhex(md5('foobar'))` using the function referenced works. But there is a problem with that function. If your password has a certain combination of letters the result is one letter off...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works perfectly. Using the function in the comments like this will produce a base64 password that LDAP will accept.

`select BASE64_ENCODE(unhex('mysql-md5-encoded-password')`

Comment: I am glad you got it working. Did you figure out what was causing the errors you experienced with the missing character?

Comment: yes for some reason the line of the stored function that had `DECLARE first_char BLOB(1);` I had it as `DECLARE first_char CHAR(1);`