# How to use base 64 encoding of simple table

Tags: mysql

**My Table::**

```
create table test_image (
  id int(10) not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(25) not null default '',
  image blob not null
);
```

---

```
SELECT * from test_image;
```

---

How to apply **Base 64** encoding in this table here

i want to convert binary image data to textual result

Any Ideas

Comment: In MySQL? You can not. Why not do that in application?

Comment: *cough* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_to-base64 *cough* but that wont work very well with your blob, if I remember right text functions are limited to varchar4000

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using expressJS ..... please Have a look at the detailed question i posted here http://stackoverflow.com/q/18842874/2609157

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358500/base64-encode-in-mysql). Googling your question before asking will save you a lot of time.