# Bash: Base64 encode 1 column in a very large .csv and output to new file

Tags: mysql, bash, csv, base64

I've tried using the code below but the csv file has over 80 million lines (roughly 25gb) and some of the special characters seem to break the echo command. The csv has 2 columns separated by a comma.
ex:

```
blah, blah2
data1,data2
line3,fd$$#$%T%^Y%&$$B
somedata,%^&%^&%^&^
```

The goal is to take that second column and base64 is to get ready to import into a sql db. I'm doing a base64 encode on the second column so there's unicode support etc and no character will corrupt the db.
 I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing this that won't break on special chars etc.

```
awk -F "," '
    {
        "echo "$2" | base64" | getline x
        print $1, x
    }
' OFS=',' input.csv > base64.csv
```

Error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")") : 
not foundrf :
not found201054 : 
not foundth : 
not foundz09  
| base64' (Too many open files)ut.csv FNR=1078) fatal: cannot open pipe `echo q1w2e3r4
```

Comment: another issue im finding is the second column may contain a comma inside the data too. anyway to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not quoting the argument to `echo` in the the `awk` script.

But there's no need to use `awk` for this, `bash` can parse the file directly.

```
IFS=, while read -r col1 col2
do
    base64=$(base64 <<<"$col2")
    echo "$col1, $base64"
done < input.csv > base64.csv
```

Comment: getting errors: ./base64.sh: line 2: while: command not found
./base64.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
./base64.sh: line 3: `do'

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't be able to find the `while` command, it's a built-in command.

Comment: When I search for other examples of that error, they're always due to some kind of typo.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal is to take that **second** column and **base64**

With **`awk`** `getline` function:

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]*' '{ cmd="echo \042"$2"\042 |  base64"; cmd | getline v; 
        close(cmd); print $1","v }' input.csv > base64.csv
```

The `base64.csv` contents (for your current input):

```
blah,YmxhaDIK
data1,ZGF0YTIK
line3,ZmQyNzMwOCMkJVQlXlklJjI3MzA4Qgo=
somedata,JV4mJV4mJV4mXgo=
```

Comment: I wasn't clear to the output being col1,col2 to be output as col1,base64col2. youres just outputs the base64'd second column only

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your MySQL command-line client:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL '/tmp/filename.txt' INTO TABLE tbl FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`

You can reorder fields if needed and apply special expressions if you need to remove special characters, concatenate strings, convert date format, etc. If you still really need base64 conversion, MySQL versions 5.6 and later have a native function for that (`TO_BASE64()`), while there is a UDF for the older ones. See [base64 encode in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358500/base64-encode-in-mysql)

However, as long as your columns do not have commas, `LOAD DATA INFILE` will be able to handle it, and you can save some disk space by avoiding the conversion.

For details on how to use LOAD DATA INFILE, see MySQL manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

You will need to authenticate to MySQL as a user with the LOAD privilege, and have `local-infile` option enabled (e.g. by passing `--local-infile=1` on the command line.

Comment: how well does this work with huge datasets with the input and conversions as far as overhead etc

Comment: The overhead is about as low as you could possibly make it without writing your own custom-crafted input converter in C. In practical terms, you will barely be able to measure it in a benchmark unless it is very very complicated. Short of implementing your own custom crafted low-level tablespace importer, you cannot beat it with anything else.